# Sync iCal on iPod Touch

Tags: ipod-touch, data-synchronization, mobileme, ical

Is this normal that the events I add in my calendar on my iPod doesn't show up on the calendar on my MobileMe account ? Do I have to do something on the iPod to not only be sync from the MobileMe Account but also push the new events on the could ?

Note : I have Mail set up with my MobileMe information on the iPod. This works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what calendar you're adding the events to. In the Calendar app, in the top left, there is a Calendars button which lists all the calendars on the phone. You should hopefully see your MobileMe calendars in there, labelled as such in their own section. The theory goes that you should see any events on MobileMe that you've added to the calendars listed under the MobileMe section of the screen.

I would guess you're adding the events on the iPod touch to the wrong calendar, but it could be there's a separate issue. You'll need to check what Calendar is selected on the Event screen when you're adding or editing the event.